# Adding constraints for UIButton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I just create a app ,that have 3 `UIButton` in vertical mode one by one.I add some autolayout to fix my image .but it differ for different simulator device. I create uibutton using story board .And i name it `Button1,Button2,Button 3`

This is my `viewcontrller.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var titleL: UILabel!
```

I too see some post to solve constraint .Like this code: (for `button1` alone here i added )

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1 , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1 , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1 , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

I need to keep my button like this image

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you need to set three button in vertical mode like this.For that you can make use this two tutorial by raywenderlich. In that first tutorial they will explanin about two autolayout method. Like you need they use UIView to explain

[Tutorial 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints)

Hop after read this sure you will get some idea for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Autolayout is difficult to explain in words but the best tutorial on autolayout I have ever seen is lecture 9 in the most recent Stanford iOS course. Here is a link:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/8.-view-controller-lifecycle/id961180099?i=335430612&mt=2

Autolayout starts around minute 22 of that video. I highly recommend it.

Comment: thanks But there are many videos.In that how can i find for my solution

Comment: It is lecture number 9. It goes into great detail how to do autolayout properly. You will find it very helpful.